# Compare old HTML table with new one and animate the changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page initially loads, it loads this table from a PHP file that keeps the table updated:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr id="1"><td>Item 1</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">1</td></tr>
    <tr id="2"><td>Item 2</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">2</td></tr>
    <tr id="3"><td>Item 3</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">3</td></tr>
    <tr id="4"><td>Item 4</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">4</td></tr>
    <tr id="5"><td>Item 5</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then every 10 seconds I load through ajax again the table (which might have been updated from mysql) to compare it with the first one and act accordingly, let's say the updated table looks like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr id="1"><td>Item 1</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">1</td></tr>
    <tr id="32"><td>Item 32</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">2</td></tr>
    <tr id="5"><td>Item 5</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">3</td></tr>
    <tr id="21"><td>Item 21</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">4</td></tr>
    <tr id="7"><td>Item 7</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">5</td></tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that if I just load the table (replace it) its hard to keep the track of what is happening, so I want to make it animated.

I want to compare each time the "current" version of the table with the "updated" one, and if there are changes, act accordingly:

- Removed items: fadeOut and destroyed
- New items: Append in its new position and fadeIn

Having the two html tables, how would I compare them and make the changes?

Comment: Instead of comparing 2 HTML tables, you should return the new data via a json object, then simply check the IDs that don't match and do your animations.

Comment: Do you want to animate the changes based on id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use this as a base:

```
  <html>
  Old Table <br />
  <table id="mytable1">
<tr id="1"><td>Item 1</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">1</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td>Item 2</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">2</td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td>Item 3</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">3</td></tr>
<tr id="4"><td>Item 4</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">4</td></tr>
<tr id="5"><td>Item 5</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">5</td></tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  New Table <br />
  <table id="mytable2">
<tr id="1"><td>Item 1</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">1</td></tr>
<tr id="32"><td>Item 32</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">2</td></tr>
<tr id="5"><td>Item 5</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">3</td></tr>
<tr id="21"><td>Item 21</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">4</td></tr>
<tr id="7"><td>Item 7</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">5</td></tr>
  </table>


  <input type="button" onclick="merge('mytable1', 'mytable2')" value="merge" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function merge(id1, id2){
    var tbl1 = $('#'+id1);
    var tbl2 = $('#'+id2);
    var currentIds =  new Array();
    var newIds =  new Array();
    $(tbl2).find('tr').each(function(){
        newIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    var newIdsStr = ","+ newIds.join(',')+",";
    console.log(newIdsStr);
    $(tbl1).find('tr').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var index = newIdsStr.indexOf(","+id+",");
        //console.log(id);
        if( index == -1){
            $(this).hide(500);
        }
        else{
            //console.log(newIdsStr.substring(0, index) + newIdsStr.substring( index + id.length + 1));
            newIdsStr = newIdsStr.substring(0, index) + newIdsStr.substring( index + id.length + 1);
        }
    });
    if(newIdsStr.length==1)
        return;
    var finalArr = newIdsStr.substring(1, newIdsStr.length -1).split(',');
    console.log(finalArr);
    for(var i=0;i<finalArr.length; i++){
        var tr = $('<tr id="'+finalArr[i]+'"><td>Item '+finalArr[i]+'</td><td>bla bla bla</td><td class="sort">5</td></tr>');
        $(tr).css('opacity','0').appendTo(tbl1).fadeTo(500, 1);     
    }
    console.log(newIdsStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like Christian Varga said..if you compare the two using javascript before displaying it, then using the id for the row in the table, you could highlight it whatever way you want, like Document.getElementById("tablRow7").InnerHTML = "some highlighted version of the table row"

Comment: I don't want to highlight it. If an item gets removed, I want to slide it up so all the other items below will come up with the animation. Same as if a new item is added after the first one with slidedown animation, all the items below it will go down aswell. Could I do it by comparing the two json objects?